What does "CoRR" classification mean in papers on openreview.net?
I frequently encounter papers on OpenReview.net that are classified as "CoRR 2024". While I understand this might be related to arXiv classifications, I haven't been able to find a clear explanation of what CoRR means in this context.
So I have some specific questions:

What does CoRR stand for in this context?
What's the relationship between CoRR classification and arXiv?
Why do many preprints on OpenReview have this classification or other type papers?


CoRR is just the Computing Research Repository in arXiv, basically the computer science section of arXiv, which probably started with a different name (CoRR) before it joined arXiv.
More information can be found at arXiv info: Computer Science archive

If I publish my paper on another preprint server, will it also be included in CoRR by openreview? For example, Elsevier's preprint server.

@Junhao No, OpenReview just show CoRR's contents, OpenReview and CoRR are not related.

I found a related paper. I wonder if CoRR is similar to DBLP?

@Junhao No. I'm unsure how to make the answer even clearer than it has already been stated but: CoRR was a preprint server that at one time merged with arXiv but retained it's name. DBLP is not a preprint server. DBLP merely indexes CS papers published elsewhere.
